# Pandas: change value of a cell based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
STRINGS      NUMBER         
hello        10
byebye       9
hello        20
hello        21
```

Stucked on this:

Changing the value of `NUMBER` cells when its value is greater than 10 and 'hello' in `STRINGS` is at the same index.

I tried:

```
df.loc[df['STRING'] == 'hello' > 10, 'NUMBER'] = 100
```

or

```
df.loc[x.STRING.str.contains('hello') > 10, 'NUMBER'] = 100
```

The results should be this:

```
 STRINGS      NUMBER
  hello        10
  byebye       9
  hello        100
  hello        100
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need chain both conditions with `()` and `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df.loc[(df['STRING'] == 'hello') & (df['NUMBER'] > 10), 'NUMBER'] = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

via `np.where`:

```
df['NUMBER'] = np.where((df['STRINGS'] == 'hello') & (df['NUMBER'] > 10), 100, df['NUMBER'])
```